# For rooted device: Turn on GPS in 4.0 and above

Tags: android, gps, root

I am working on a project for rooted device and I wanted to turn on location services to track location without the user interaction, programmatically.
I have created an sms BroadcastReceiver and turning on GPS in it.

I found this:

```
public void turnGPSOn() {

  Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");

  intent.putExtra("enabled", true);

  this.sendBroadcast(intent);

  String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), 

  Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

  if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled final Intent poke = new Intent();

poke.setClassName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");

  poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);

  poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));

  this.sendBroadcast(poke);

}
```

But this is giving error and I do not understand what to do.

NOTE: I am just a beginner. Using Android studio. my testing device is on android 5.1.1

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I73yW.png)

Comment: sendBroacast, Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED); : are in red text within android studio @Pragadees

Comment: yes its won't work above 4.0 so use com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0 or 7